# Что означает конструкция some_function(params)(x)

Tags: python

Разбираю код на Питоне и не пойму, что означает вызов функции 
x_class = Convolution2D(num_anchors, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid',   kernel_initializer='uniform', name='rpn_out_class')(x)

То есть вызов функции имеет вид: x_class = Convolution2D(params)(x)

В других языках я таких конструкции не встречал. (params) - это понятно, но к чему тут вторые скобки с иксом? Либо просто скажите как называется такая конструкция - поищу по названию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В питоне функция - это полноценный объект, который можно как передавать в качестве аргумента, так и (данный случай) возвращать в качестве значения.

То есть, Convolution2D(params) внутри себя по переданным параметрам конструирует некоторую функцию и возвращает её в качестве результата, которая сразу же вызывается с аргументом x. И уже результат вызова этой второй функции записывается в x_class.

Возможно, этот упрощённый пример поможет вам лучше понять, как это работает:

```
def get_operation(symbol):

    def plus(a, b):
        return a+b

    def minus(a, b):
        return a-b

    if symbol == '+':
        return plus
    if symbol == '-':
        return minus

operation = get_operation('+')
print(operation(5, 3))
# Напечатает: 8

operation = get_operation('-')
print(operation(5, 3))
# Напечатает: 2

# И вот пример, где возвращаемая функция вызывается сразу, как в вашем вопросе:
print(
    get_operation('+')(4, 7)
    )
# Напечатает: 11
```

Comment: Ага, вот теперь понятно. Спасибо!